# BiBTeX Name Order

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

When I compile my bibliography it lists the names as "John Smith" instead of "Smith, John".  How do I change this?  By the way, I am using BibDesk.

Comment: BibDesk is only a database manager; what influences the typesetting of the references is the argument to `\bibliographystyle` in your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @egreg put in his comment, the appearance of names in the reference list is managed by the bibliography style.

To give a simple example of this using the .bib file:

```
@book{abk,
      author = "Adam Man and Eve Woman",
      title = "This book",
      publisher = "Men \& Women",
      year = 2025
}
```

The .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\begin{document}
Found in \cite{abk}.

\bibliography{sample2}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

> [image]

but the .tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\begin{document}
Found in \cite{abk}.

\bibliography{sample2}
\end{document}
```

, which differs only in the `\bibliographystyle` line, produces the output

> [image]